# jQuery Autocomplete get source option

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

How to get a list of the items for autocomplete? I mean, the source values (hints for autocomplete).
I tried this:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete('option', 'source');
```

But this doesn't work.

Sorry for my poor Enlish and poor jQuery knowledge.

Comment: do you want to set items for autocomplete or want to get selected values?

Comment: _'source'_ in quotes?

Comment: When we initialize autocomplete we give it some values. Hints. For example, ["Python", "Perl", "Java", "Basic"].
I need to get this values.

Comment: read about autocomplete here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Luthando Loot, please, I need a more concrete link, than link to a whole manual.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna to set item for `autocomplete`

Try like this

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({

 source : ["dum1","dum2"]

});
```

After initialize

for getting

```
var source = $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete( "option", "source" );
console.log(source)
```

for setting

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete( "option", "source", [ "dum3", "dum4", ] );
```

Comment: No, i need to GET items. Get suggestions for autocomplete.

Comment: nope. Just [element]. The output is just like $("#autocomplete").

Comment: can you provide the initialize part ? i think i got your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. But if you tell me, what are you thinking about, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source" )

console.log(source)
```

response: ['val1','val2','val3']

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.